# Cumulative Sum based on dates in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, cumulative-sum

I have a set of claims data. This data only has three columns, TransactionDate, ClaimNumber, ReserveNet.

I have been asked to pin point the maximum ReserveNet amount based on the dates grouped by claim number. Lets say we have a claim with a ClaimNumber of A1 and we have 6 transactions for this claim.

01/01/2022 - ReserveNet £1000

03/01/2022 - ReserveNet £3000

05/01/2022 - ReserveNet £5000

06/01/2022 - ReserveNet -£1000

09/01/2022 - ReserveNet £2000

25/01/2022 - ReserveNet -£10000

I know that the maximum ReserveNet was achieved on 09/01/2022 with a cumulative sum of £10,000.

I have code that works fine for a standard cumulative view, but cannot work out how to get it to stop at the maximum.

One step I tried was duplicating the table in PowerBI, sorting the ClaimNumber and TransactionDate (desc) and adding in a custom column:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each Table.AddColumn( #"Added Index", "CumulativeSum", each List.Sum( Table.SelectRows( #"Added Index", each [ClaimNumber] = [ClaimNumber] and [Index] <= [Index] )[NetIncurred] ), type number))`

But that just brings back a result of Table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @horseyride If you were to sum the values from 01/01/2022 - 09/01/2022 you would find the total is £10,000. The lowest reserve sum would be on 25/01/2022 when it drops to £0.

I need to be able to reflect in a pivot table the maximum reserve and corresponding date for each claim.

A measure might suffice, however someone who tried to help me elsewhere advised that it would be best to create a duplicate table in Power BI, add that column and then create measurse off the back of it.

Comment: @horseyride I'm afraid my knowledge of Power BI is not exactly top drawer, but I am getting better at it.

I've modified my load script to emulate the one you made. The only problem I have is that the final stage "MaxCumTotal" brings back a total of the highest amount of all claims as opposed to bringing back the maxium for each claim with the date.

Comment: Check that the column names of your data are an exact match to the column names you are using in the code adapted from mine, including spaces and cApiTALization   My example works for the sample data shown, so it gets tricky to help you from there

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @horseyride for your help. I managed to get your version to work in the end, however someone has helped me with two measures that work and ultimately I found that more straightforward and that is the method I went with.

For anyone else who might look at this the DAX Measures are:

```
Cumulative = CALCULATE(SUM('Claims_Transactional'[ReserveNetAmount]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Claims_Transactional'),[ClaimNumber]=MAX('Claims_Transactional'[ClaimNumber])&&[ClaimTransactionDate]<=MAX('Claims_Transactional'[ClaimTransactionDate])))
```

And

```
MAX Cumulative = MAXX(ALLSELECTED('Claims_Transactional'),[Cumulative])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this which adds a column with the maximum cumulative value reached for each ClaimNumber. Assumes data comes in sorted by date, or add that yourself as an early step:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ClaimNumber", type text}, {"TransactionDate", type date}, {"ReserveNet", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ClaimNumber"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "CumTotal", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[ReserveNet],[Index]+1))),
    #"MaxCum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Cum Total", "MaxCumTotal", each List.Max(#"Cum Total"[CumTotal])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"MaxCum Total",{"Index", "CumTotal"})
    in #"Removed Columns"
, type table [ClaimNumber=text, TransactionDate=date, ReserveNet=number, MaxCumTotal =number ]}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ClaimNumber"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ClaimNumber", type text}, {"TransactionDate", type date}, {"ReserveNet", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(   #"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index" ,"Cum",(x)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [ClaimNumber]=x[ClaimNumber] and [Index]<=x[Index])[ReserveNet])??0),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom" ,"MaxCumTotal",(x)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [ClaimNumber]=x[ClaimNumber])[Cum])??0)
in #"Added Custom2"
```

[image]